# Getting error when using FFTW plan as threadprivate

Tags: c, static, openmp, fftw

I am trying to use OpenMP on a code doing some complex algebra using `FFTW` operations. Each thread needs to work separately using its own work arrays. Therefore I followed this answer ( [Reusable private dynamically allocated arrays in OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592378/reusable-private-dynamically-allocated-arrays-in-openmp?noredirect=1&lq=1) ) and tried to use the `threadprivate` functionality. The `FFTW` plans and workspace variables need to be used many times in the code in multiple parallel segments.

The following is a test code. However, it gives all kinds of errors (segmentation faults, etc.) at the line `p1=fftw_plan_ ...`. Any idea what I am doing wrong ? This seems to work well just with arrays but is not working for the `FFTW` plan. Can an `FFTW` plan be shared by threads but working on their separate data segments `inpd`, `outc1`, `outc2` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int npts2, id;
    
    static double *inpd;
    static fftw_complex *outc1, *outc2;
    static fftw_plan p1, p2;
    static int npts2stat;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(inpd,outc1,outc2,p1,p2,npts2stat)
    
    npts2=1000;
    
    #pragma omp parallel private(id) shared(npts2)
    {
        id=omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Thread %d: Allocating threadprivate memory \n",id);
        
        npts2stat=npts2;
        
        printf("step1 \n");
        inpd=malloc(sizeof(double)*npts2stat);
        outc1=fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*npts2stat);
        outc2=fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*npts2stat);
        printf("step2 \n");
        // CODE COMPILES FINE BUT STOPS HERE WITH ERROR
        p1=fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(npts2stat,inpd,outc1,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        p2=fftw_plan_dft_1d(npts2stat,outc1,outc2,FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        printf("step3 \n");
    }
    
    // multiple omp parallel segments with different threads doing some calculations on complex numbers using FFTW
    
    #pragma omp parallel private(id)
    {
        id=omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Thread %d: Deallocating threadprivate memory \n",id);
        free(inpd);
        fftw_free(outc1);
        fftw_free(outc2);
        fftw_destroy_plan(p1);
        fftw_destroy_plan(p2);
    }
}
```

EDIT1: I seem to have solved the segmentation fault issue below. However if you have a better way of doing this, that will be helpful. For example, I don't know if a single plan for all threads is sufficient because it is acting on different data `inpd` private to different threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the section on Thread Safety in FFTW manual makes it pretty clear that FFTW planner should be called only one thread at a time. This seems to have solved the segmentation fault issue.

```
#pragma omp critical
        {
        p1=fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(npts2stat,inpd,outc1,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        p2=fftw_plan_dft_1d(npts2stat,outc1,outc2,FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        }
```