# Can't parallelize operation with OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

i am working on a project that i am trying to use parallel programming with `OpenMP`. the part is using one of `OpenCV` functions for image left and right, i want it to happen in parallel inside visual studio i set the `Project properties` -> `C/C++`->`Language`->`openmp support to yes`.

in my main function use :

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
   omp_set_num_threads(2);
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
      if(thread_is == 0){
        //image left calc goes here
      }

      if(thread_id == 1){
        image right calc goes here
      }

   }
   return 0;
}
```

when benchmarking execution times this is doesn't so stable.
is it the currect way the parallelize this tasks?
thanks!

Comment: First, take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448318/openmp-omp-parallel-vs-omp-parallel-for. Also, see [OpenMP tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/).

Comment: What is not stable? How does the performance look like? The code could be correct, but I have no idea what opencv images do.

Comment: Go through this http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/